# Echo a blank line

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I'm having trouble having the following code echo an blank line to the file when it encounters a blank line. How should I go about this?

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type Setup.ini|find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%%B"
if defined line (
    call set "line=echo.%%line:PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: TRUE=PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: FALSE%%"
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >>Setup.ini.replaced%~x1
    )
)
```

Comment: @mattedgod -- Not any python I've ever seen ...

Comment: I have no memory of this Python...

Comment: @crnlx [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14201258/2) is _not_ a good edit. Please do not change tags unless you are absolutely certain that what you are doing is correct. You can ask the OP to clarify in the comments if needed.

Comment: It's just a windows batch file. I'm very inexperienced with writing code. But this just goes through a file, finds a line and replaces it. But it also deletes the blank lines, but I would like to keep them intact. I thought "echo." would do this, but I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Ben - my bad. Serves me well for editing just before rushing to a meeting.

Comment: Please click the checkmark under the answer to mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2):

When a blank line is encountered the `line` variable will be set to blank which deletes the variable.  You already have the check for when it is defined.  **Just add a check for when it is not defined.**

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type Setup.ini|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: TRUE=PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: FALSE%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X >>Setup.ini.replaced%~x1
    )
    if not defined line echo.>>Setup.ini.replaced%~x1
)
```

**Extra:** Here is the code again, but with my recommended edits using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`.

```
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('type Setup.ini ^| find /n /v ""') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        set "line=!line:PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: TRUE=PRINTER_JAM_SENSOR_PRESENT: FALSE!"
        echo(!line!>>Setup.ini.replaced%~x1
    )
    if not defined line echo.>>Setup.ini.replaced%~x1
)
```